# How can I configure my front-end JavaScript application?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript application that needs to interact with many different service endpoints. E.g. the application makes calls to `api.mydomain.com` and `users.mydomain.com`. The user gets the front-end application by visiting `mydomain.com`. I would like to set up a test version of my services, meaning I will now have `users-test.mydomain.com`, `api-test.mydomain.com`, etc. The test version of the application will be located at `test.mydomain.com`.

The JavaScript powering the normal and test versions will be identical, but all of the endpoints will be different. What is the best way to configure the front-end to allow this domain (test, production) specific switching?

Comment: Need more information, are you using a framework or pure javascript??

Comment: Do you already know task runners? Like Grunt or Gulp. They allow you to run ~tasks according to your environment, so, for example, you can set an environment variable based on the command line flags, and use it inside your server. Actually, many frameworks already had this built-in, like Play Framework for Java.

Comment: @daymannovaes Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the URL and use an object to ping the correct back-end API:

```
// remove http:// and https://, and remove path info
var domain = window.location.href.replace(/.*\/\//, '').replace(/\/.*/, '');
var url = {
    "mydomain.com": {
        users: "users.mydomain.com",
        api: "api.mydomain.com"
    },
    "test.mydomain.com": {
        users: "users-test.mydomain.com",
        api: "api-test.mydomain.com"
    }
};
```

Using these variables, you can now ping `url[domain].users` and `url[domain].api`.